# change the Stripe button text "Pay" to other text

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I have the code below to use Stripe. But the button that appears has the text like "Pay 10.05". Do you know how to change the text 'Pay' to other text?

With data-panel-label and data-label appears an error ": expected".

Do you know how to properly change the 'Pay' to other text?

```
$(function () {
    let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "{{config('services.stripe.key')}}",
        image: "",
        locale: "auto",
        token: (token) => {
            document.querySelector('#stripeToken').value = token.id;
            document.querySelector('#paymentForm').submit();
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        stripe.open({
            name: 'Payment',
            description: '{{session('name')}}',
            amount: '{{session('totalStripe')}}',
            currency: 'eur',
            allowRememberMe: false
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize that with panelLabel option. Read more [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional)

```
let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "{{config('services.stripe.key')}}",
    image: "",
    locale: "auto",
    panelLabel: "GiveMeMoney"
    token: (token) => {
        document.querySelector('#stripeToken').value = token.id;
        document.querySelector('#paymentForm').submit();
    }
});
```